# Idiomatic French expression for "you scratch my back, I’ll scratch yours"?

Tags: expressions

I did someone a favour the other day without expecting anything in return. Then she insisted on returning the favour somehow, so I asked her to do a little something for me.

I wonder if the following sounds idiomatic enough to express the idea of mutual back scratching?

> Dans ce cas-là, voyons ça comme **un échange de bons procédés** !

I cannot seem to find a dictionary entry or a webpage that refers to this expression as a direct translation of the "you scratch my back, I’ll scratch yours". So I'm not sure.

At any rate, I’m looking for an expression to denote a casual quid pro quo arrangement where you agree to scratch someone’s back so they scratch yours.

Comment: It's similar but way too formal for a direct translation.

Comment: donnant-donnant...

Comment: This might be helpful, but as a non-native (and very average) French speaker, I can't vouch for its accurateness: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/you-scratch-my-back-ill-scratch-yours.856089/

Comment: @GAMPUB J'ai pensé comme vous, puis ensuite quand j'ai regardé la définition au TLFi, on cite Ac. _qu'on ne veut donner une chose qu'en recevant une autre chose_, c'est-à-dire _à condition de_. Ça m'apparaît légèrement différent (et de mon usage et) d'une constatation qu'il y a eu _échange de bons procédés_ ou un désir de procéder _au pair_. Et donc il y a aussi _gagnant-gagnant_ mais ça semble davantage technique et moins usuel. Si vous avez une solution avec quelques explications, j'aimerais bien la lire. Merci !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Échange de bons procédés* is fine.

I would also suggest *[rendre la pareille](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/rendre_la_pareille)* or *[renvoyer l'ascenseur](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/renvoyer_l%E2%80%99ascenseur)*.

For "you scratch my back, I’ll scratch yours" meaning "Do this, and we're even", I would say:

> Fais ça et on sera quitte.

Comment: Hi. Essentially, what I want to say here is: "Do this, and we're even", or "Do this, and we consider it as {un échange de bons procédés}". How would you use those two expressions in this particular context?

Comment: Not sure how to use the expressions I suggested with your sentence. I'd rather translate it : *Fais ça et on sera quitte*.